# Serve LAS/LAZ data from server to frontend

Tags: las, laz, potree

I have the following architecture:

- Frontend: Vue3 w. OpenLayers7 (Typescript)
- Backend: FastAPI (Python)
- WebMapServer: GeoServer 2.23

I would like to display LAS/LAZ LIDAR data through Potree and I'd like to know if there where a good practice to serve those data to the frontend from the server where they are?

Is it possible to use GeoServer for this purpose or should I simply host the raw files on the host machine and get it directly in the frontend (I guess, it's really not a good way to do this...) or host them in a specific DB and get it through the classic backend -> frontend way?

Comment: https://copc.io/

Comment: Thank you @bugmenot123 ! Can you relate me some feedback ? Did you personnaly used this ? What are the pros/cons in your opinion ?